# automatically restart jira service when it goes down

Tags: linux, service, port, jira, pid

I have installed Jira ( atlassian-jira-software-7.3.7-standalone) on centos 7 in aws. I use "**start-jira.sh**" shell script to start the server and it works just fine.

recently I observed that the process gets suddenly crashed and I am not able to access jira. my typical "**ps aux | grep tomcat**" result is,

```
root      3937  9.3 78.3 3283156 1474756 pts/0 Sl   11:23   4:58 //bin/java 
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/atlassian-jira-software-7.3.7-
 standalone/conf/logging.properties -
Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms384m -
Xmx768m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Datlassian.standalone=JIRA -
Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true -
Dmail.mime.decodeparameters=true -
Dorg.dom4j.factory=com.atlassian.core.xml.InterningDocumentFactory -
XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -
Datlassian.plugins.startup.options= -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -
Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -classpath 
/opt/atlassian-jira-software-7.3.7-
standalone/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/atlassian-jira-software-7.3.7-
standalone/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/atlassian-jira-software-
7.3.7-standalone -Dcatalina.home=/opt/atlassian-jira-software-7.3.7-
standalone -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/atlassian-jira-software-7.3.7-
standalone/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

I want to monitor this service (jira) when it gets started and notify me when it crashed and also try to reconnect it on its own.

I have tried "**monit**" tool for that but I did not find any "**pid**" file associated with that service. and the main thing is I am not starting my jira by using **"service jira start"** I don't want to do that. also, jira server runs on port **80** in my case.

is there any way this could happen?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because its asking for a software or program recommendation. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use supervisord for this

http://supervisord.org/introduction.html

Comment: I did it by writing script which check "ps aux" status for that service, and if it not there it will simply restart the service.
And i put it in cron to run an every minute